# AccessDeniedPath path in ConfigureApplicationCookie is always redirecting to http, instead of https. My site is https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In asp.net core 2.2, I am setting below

But on redirect it always goes to http, instead of https. if any insight which setting I should put, as my site if already https. And it goes to http because of above redirect.

I tried https redirect but it does not solve the issue

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie
o.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
o.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
```

Comment: Share us your crruent `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

try UseHttpsRedirection() in Startup.cs class to enforce the https redirection

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    //to enforce https redirection
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

for reference [Enforce Https in Asp.Net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)